# How to create a relation between two tables using PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to create a relation between two tables using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: What storage engine are you using for your DB? AFAIK only InnoDB supports relational databases in MySQL.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This only works if you use `InnoDB` as storage engine. Then you have a link `Relation view` besides `Print view`:

[image: Relation view]

If you click this you get to another site where you can select the relations for all columns that have indecies defined on them (following the pattern `table->column`).

[image: Link to]