# Displaying data from different tables in a view

Tags: yii

I have a requirement where I would like to display a list of records and the information from each record can come from a umber of tables. To further explain I have the following tables:

Table srp with columns id (PK), srpname, idbusiness (FK), idsite (FK)

Table business with columns id (PK), businessname

Table site with columns id (PK), sitename

Table srpprimary with columns id (PK), idsrp (FK), pname

Table srpdepname with columns id (PK), idsrp (FK), dname

An srp can have multiple entries in the table srpprimary and one entry in each of the other tables business, site, srpdepname

What I would like is to display an srp record along with all the pname entries in the table srpprimary, the dname from the table srpdepname and the actual business name and site name.

I looked at the CListView but could not see how I could get this additional data.

Any suggestions on how the above could best be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

e25taki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you in this question and in  your next project I recommended you to use database  relations :

1- prraper your datbase

2- write your relations on paper bettwen tables

3- do it (use phpmyadmin for example  ):

- by GUI methode

[How to create a relation between two tables using PHPMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554903/how-to-create-a-relation-between-two-tables-using-phpmyadmin)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdQGFZwP7Xc

- Sql method

  ALTER TABLE Orders
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders
  FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
  REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)

4- now you can use yii gii to create your code and all you relations will be save in model class

5- load data in view will be so so easy now :

For Example if your model is like  :

```
<?php
..
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'co' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country', 'co_id'),
        'events' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Events', 'city'),
        'news' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'News', 'city'), /// here 
        'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Users', 'city'),
    );
}
...
?>
```

So we can access to all news table that related to current city by call it as :

```
echo $model->news->title;
```

Answer (score 1):

### It's all about the relations in your models.

With correct relations, you can access data like:

```
$srp    = Srp::model()->findByPk(1);
$sites  = $srp->sites;  // gets an active record-array with a HAS_MANY-relation
$site   = $srp->site;   // gets the active record directly with a HAS_ONE-relation
```

Considering the code generation in Gii, you'll have a much easier time if you rename your foreign keys so they end with "id" or "_id". That way, you'll get sensiblle relations automatically when you generate your models. (Though they still might need to be tweaked a bit to suit your needs.)

With your new relations, you can create a listview like this in your view:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Srp');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view',
));
```

And access your data something like this (_view.php) :

```
<b>Id:</b>  // Or better yet: echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id'));
<?php echo $data->id; ?>
<br />

<b>Business:</b>
<?php echo $data->business->name; ?>
<br />

<b>Site:</b>
<?php echo $data->site->name; ?>
<br />

<b>Depname:</b>
<?php foreach ($data->srpdepnames as $dep): ?>
    <?php echo $dep->dname; ?>, 
<?php endforeach ?>
<br />

<b>Depname:</b>
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('srpprimary_id')); ?>:</b>
<?php foreach ($data->srpprimaries as $prime ){ 
    echo CHtml::link(   // If you want links instead of just text.
        CHtml::encode($prime->pname), 
        array('SrpPrimary/View', 'id'=>$prime->id)
   );
}?>
```

(I haven't tried this, so it's not a working example. Sorry! But it should give you an idea and it's not far from the truth. )

Answer (score 0):

```
In controller.php 


public function actionQueries()
{


      $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Student', array(
        'criteria' => array(
        'with' =>'student',       
        'join' => 'INNER JOIN studentinfo si ON si.stud_id=t.id',
    )
));

$this->render('query',array(
        'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    ));

}


in a view,in tables model view make php file for ex query.php

<?php
/* @var $this StudentController */
/* @var $model Student */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Students'=>array('query'),
    //$user->name,
);


$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
    'enablePagination'=>true,
     'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'name',
      )
       ));
?>

// add your new feilds in _view.php file:

// in controller.php 

in accsessRule() add your new file for authentication for ex.queris

public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','queries'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
}
```