# managing multiple tables with same table structure in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, table-structure

I am having multiple tables with same structure and a template table which is the master for all of these tables.

Is there a way that whenever i make any changes to master table(in structure), The child tables should get updated to always keep the structure same as of the master template table.

I am using php and mysql for this operation.

For startup i am using queries like

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM 'test%'
```

and then i want help for comparing table columns

and then if a column is missing in child table then i can create that column.

Comment: If you're determined to use such a schema, couldn't you use triggers to update the child tables on master changes?

Comment: Using PHPMyAdmin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554903/how-to-create-a-relation-between-two-tables-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: @ChrisW The triggers will work for structures also???

Comment: @EisaAdil I saw the method but unfortunately i am using myisam engine.